# Almacenar números aleatorios del arreglo 1 al al arreglo 2 pero de forma invertida en PHP

Tags: php

Debo almacenar los números aleatorios del arreglo 1 al al arreglo 2 pero de forma invertida en PHP.

¿Me pueden ayudar? No sé si el for esta mal.  Al almacenarlo en el arreglo 2, solo logro mostrar el ultimo número del arreglo 1 y no todos.

```
    $num1 = $_REQUEST['numero1'];
    $arre = array();
    $arre2 = array();
    
    
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> numeros </td>";
    echo "<td>Numeros inversas</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    
    for ($i=1; $i<= $num1 ; $i++){
    $arre = rand(1,100);
    echo "<br>";
    
    echo $arre ;
    }
    echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
for ($x=$num1; $x>=1; $x--){
    $arre2 =$arre ;

echo "<br>";
echo $arre2;

}
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu pregunta dices que quieres almacenar números aleatorios en arrays. Veo que declaras dos variables que quieres usar para estos array **arre** y **arre2**. Hasta aquí bien.
Pero en el for usas $arre, no como array, sino como una variable simple. Cada iteración del for guardas en $arre un nuevo valor, elimnado el antiguo. Aquí $arre no es un array, es una variable.
La solución es fácil en lugar $arre = rand(1,100) pones $arre[] = rand(1,100). De esta manera cada nuevo número aleatorio se añade al final de la lista $arre.
Para invertir el array puedes usar la función **array_reverse($arre)** que te devuelve un array en orden inverso a $arre.

**Con un for**
Si quieres copiar un array en otro con un bucle for debes usar dos índices: una en orden creciente y otro en orden descendente.
El índice mayor en $arre es $num-1 (los índices de arrays comienzan en 0). Y el índice del array destino lo comenzamos en 0:

```
$y=0;
for ($x = $num1-1; $x >=0; $x--)
{
    $arre2[$y] = $arre[$x];
    $y++;
}
```

Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: gracias, me funciono :D